# Flattening a PCollection in Tuple Order

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm trying to add a header using the Flatten function in Apache beam. However, there doesn't appear to be a way to set the order according to the documentation: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.4.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=flatten#apache_beam.transforms.core.Flatten.

Sometimes the header is at the end of the data, and others at the top. Is there a way to set the order? Wondering if there's something I'm missing.

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:


  header = [
      ('name', 'number'),
  ]
  phones_list = [
      ('amy', '111-222-3333'),
      ('james', '222-333-4444'),
      ('amy', '333-444-5555'),
      ('carl', '444-555-6666'),
  ]

  header = p | 'Header' >> beam.Create(header)
  phones = p | 'CreatePhones' >> beam.Create(phones_list)  

  merged = ((phones,header)
            | 'MergedPColl' >> beam.Flatten())

  output = merged

  output | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('./_output')
```

Output 1:

```
('amy', '111-222-3333')
('james', '222-333-4444')
('amy', '333-444-5555')
('carl', '444-555-6666')
('name', 'number')
```

Output 2:

```
('name', 'number')
('amy', '111-222-3333')
('james', '222-333-4444')
('amy', '333-444-5555')
('carl', '444-555-6666')
```

Answer (score 2):

`Flatten` is a transformer that works on PCollections. To make the merging work in parallel, I don't think they can guarantee that the order is preserved; which is consistent to the unordered nature of the resulting PCollection.

But if your only purpose is to add the header in the top, you can use the `header` argument of [`textio.WriteToText()`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py).

> >
>         header (str): String to write at beginning of file as a header.        If not :data:`None` and **append_trailing_newlines** is set, `\n`` will be added.

```
phones | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(
  # Feel free to make your own header format.
  './_output', header="('name', 'number')")
```

More generally to preserve the sequence of original input, I would augment the input data with a sequence number. After beam's parallel transformation (carrying the sequence number for each element), you can always "recover" the original order by sorting on that sequence number as a post-processing step (in non-parallel mode).